# How to add all netgroup members to a group

Tags: pam, ldap, nsswitch

I have multiple virtualized servers, all configured to use LDAP for their passwd/shadow (in `nsswitch.conf`) and authentication (PAM).

I would like to have an easily configurable set of users who will be able to read logs on any of the servers. This means they need to be a member of a distro-specific supplementery group (eg. `systemd-journal` on systemd based distros, `adm` on Debian, etc.).

One idea I had was to make a netgroup in LDAP called eg. `log-reading-users` which would represent the set of users. I configured `nsswitch.conf` to get netgroups from LDAP.

Then I tried adding them to the groups in `/etc/group` like this:

```
adm:x:4:+@log-reading-users
```

But it didn't work.

Then I tried using `/etc/security/group.conf`:

```
# group.conf
*;*;@log-reading-users;Al0000-24000;adm
```

And adding at the end of `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth    optional            pam_group.so
```

It did work for `ssh`, `login`, and `su` with password, but when using `sudo`, `su` from root without password, or when cron is running user's crontab entry, the supplementary group IDs are not being added.

Is there a better way to do this?
Maybe something with `initgroups` in `nsswitch.conf` ?